# Need for a domain model in a service in 3 tier architecture?

Tags: java, architecture, architectural-patterns, entity

I am building an API Rest with Spring Boot and I would like to clarify a concept about my architecture, to see if the community can help me.

Imagine that in my database I have a table called `Person`. I am mounting an architecture based on three layer architecture. The general scheme would be as follows:

- On the one hand I have the `PersonDao.java`, which will be in charge of accessing the database to retrieve the tuples from the `Person` table. To do this, it uses a class called `PersonEntity.java`, which contains (as attributes) all the columns of the table. `PersonDao.java` is going to return an object from the `PersonModel.java` class. `PersonModel.java` is the class that represents the `Person` business model.
- On the other hand, I have the `PersonService.java`, which is responsible for carrying out the business logic of my application. This service calls `PersonaDao.java` to access the information stored in the database. `PersonService.java` works with objects of the `PersonModel.java` class, since this class represents the business objects of my application. `PersonService.java` will always return a `PersonDto,java`.
- Finally, `PersonController.java`. This controller will be the one that exposes the connection interface of the Rest API. He always works with DTO and communicates with `PersonService.java` through DTO as well.

`PersonController <-> (PersonDto) <-> PersonService <-> (PersonModel) <-> PersonDao <-> (PersonEntity) <-> DB`

The question is: Is it necessary to use the `PersonModel.java` class so that `PersonService.java` only works with objects of this class? Or would it be better for `PersonService.java` to work directly with objects from class `PersonEntity.java`? If I do it this way it is to maintain the principle of single responsibility, so that each layer only works with objects of its scope.

If the answer is that `PersonModel.java` is necessary to maintain the principle of single responsibility of each layer. Would something change if `JpaRepository` were used? If I ask this question it is because in many tutorials and examples I see that when `JpaRepository` is used, the services work directly with the entities. In this case, shouldn't we create a class that represents the business object for the services?

**EDIT**: In the answer to this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34084203), the architecture that makes sense in my head would be reflected, but surely it is not the most correct thing. The conclusion I come to is that each layer would use its own kind of objects. Copy / paste of the answer:

> Typically you have different layers:
>
> - A persistence layer to store data
> - Business layer to operate on data
> - A presentation layer to expose data
>
> Typically, each layer would use its own kind of objects:
>
> - Persistence Layer: Repositories, Entities
> - Business Layer: Services, Domain Objects
> - Presentation Layer: Controllers, DTOs
>
> This means each
>   layer would only work with its own objects and never ever pass them to
>   another layer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In domain driven design, the "entity" is the core business object which contains both data and related business logic. In your example, the combination of `PersonModel` and `PersonService` is the entity (I would just call it `Person`).

What you call `PersonEntity` is an implementation detail of the DAO/repository. It is not part of your domain, and you may not have this intermediate mapping object depending on your mapping technology (for example, you mentioned JPA, you might just directly annotate your real `Person` entity in that case).

DTOs are also not part of the domain layer; as the name suggests, they are for data transfer to and from the outside world. You want have a separate application service which uses DTOs for input/output and internally loads entities from the repository and invokes methods on them.

Comment: Thanks, casablanca. So if I understand correctly, if I use JPA, the class annotated with @Entity would already be the business object (also considering the service). If I use a DAO pattern, could I use PersonEntity as my business object too, without having to create the Person class (what I call PersonModel)? Or with the DAO pattern, is it always necessary to create on the one hand a class that represents the implementation detail of the DAO (related with the database) and on the other the entity that represents the business object?

Comment: @Mr.Mars: You can certainly use a single entity class with the DAO pattern, but that class would be part of the domain layer then, not the persistence layer. The goal here is to isolate the rest of the application from details of the persistence layer.